# Delete old files from server when content is updated

Tags: 7, nodes, files

When a node is updated by replacing a new file upload, old files exist on the server maintaining versions.

I want to delete old files from the server when content is updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is already discussed topic.
I found some source.

[Drupal Forum and Original Source](https://drupal.org/node/733258#comment-7427898)

After that I would create a cron job (Implementing [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7)). And insert this snippet.

I hope it works out for you.

Alternatively, if you dont want this action to happen once per day, you can insert it in [hook_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7), or hook_update. But I would go for the first method.

Do it once per day/week/whatever time period you like.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Oleg Videnov, I put the code snippet in hook_cron in my custom module.It deletes all the file that are not attached to any node.But next thing that has to be done is file name is getting changed like it appends filename_0.pdf, I want the same name e.g. filename.pdf

Comment: Can you try to flush your cache before this action ?

Comment: No result. @Oleg Videnov